# CC/CC Buck Schematic (Circuit Help)

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I found a schematic for a CC/CV buck using the LM2596-ADJ. I was curious if anyone knew exactly what the op-amp  (LM358) is doing, as well as how the potentiometers are adjusting output current and voltage. For reference, pin 2 is a switch output and pin 4 is a feedback input. The link is here:

[image: Adjustable voltage with adjustable current limit]

http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/149248/65_1301577300.gif

Comment: You seem to have a strong clue so what is it specifically you don't understand about the opamp and its function in the circuit.

Comment: The op-amp is providing the constant current feedback mechanism as it performs low-side sensing of the output current across the shunt resistor. Remember that your regulator's control loop's goal is to perturb the output until voltage at FB equals the internal reference voltage.

Comment: I get the whole sense resistor part. The feedback pin is what's getting me. It seems like the 47k and such are being powered by a pin that's an input. So the feedback pin is outputting some voltage and you use the voltage generated by the sense resistor and compare it? Also how then is the voltage adjusting potentiometers working. It's simply in parallel to the output positive terminal.

Comment: If pin 4 is your feedback pin, the feedback resistor divider is formed by \$R_{V_{adj}}\$ in series with (47k+20K)||1k

Comment: Since 1k << 47k+20k, it seems to me that the designer just decided to take advantage of the reference voltage that will appear at the feedback node. Additionally, that is in the op amp feedback path, so *I believe* this will ride the feedback pin to accurately limit current (rather than cutting off)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pot nearest the chip sets the open circuit output voltage - with no current flow, the op-amp is out of the deal and feedback is derived from the output via the pot feeding the 1k in parallel with the 1nF. The 47k and other pot are largely out of the equation because the 1k dominates that clump of components.

So, open circuit voltage is the main 20k pot nearest the chip and the 1k that form a potential divider: -

[image]

In red are the components that set the open circuit output voltage.

In blue are the components that dictate the current limit.

Comment: Great explanation of the voltage control. Perhaps adds some more on the current control and the role of the opamp. Eg. once current exceeds the threshold, the opamp begins driving pin 4 (call it Vth). Redrawing the opamp shows I*0.01 on pin 3, and Vth * R / (20K + 47K) on pin 2, where R is the resistance of the second pot. Given the op amp has negative feedback, equate the two voltages and make I the subject, to show that the opamp will limit I to R * (100 * Vth / 67K) with R adjustable from 0 to 20K.

Comment: @HeathRaftery you've saved me that job!

Comment: Thank you Andy and Heath, those were excellent and thorough answers that I appreciated you taking the time to provide.

Comment: @JacobDeen then, in the time-honoured tradition of stack exchange please consider formally accepting the answer or maybe raise another related side-question?

Comment: Sorry, still new to the site. Done.

Comment: There is a typo. It is 470k not 47k. gives 50mV across sense resistor and 20k pot at 5A output.